# Installing Qt version 4.4.3 on kubuntu getting error: narrowing conversion

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, type-conversion

I downloaded archive of Qt version 4.4.3 on kubuntu-19.10 : qt-x11-opensource-src-4.4.3.tar.gz
After unpacking it I ran the "./configure" script to support the Qt library for my machine type. It successfully gets executed without any error.
Then I run "make" and there is lot of error messages showing "narrowing conversion"for many files as below,

```
kernel/qcursor_x11.cpp:272:56: error: narrowing conversion of ‘128’ from ‘int’ to ‘char’ [-Wnarrowing]
  272 |         0xe0, 0x07, 0xc0, 0x03, 0x80, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00 };
      |

widgets/qdialogbuttonbox.cpp:250:1: error: narrowing conversion of ‘2147483650’ from ‘unsigned int’ to ‘int’ [-Wnarrowing]
  250 | };
      |
```

...

How can I stop these errors?
change in every file is not feasible(same error for many files).
Is there any configuration option(./configure --help) to stop these 'narrowing conversion' errors?

Comment: Do you treat compiler warnings as errors? Maybe you might remove that flag? It's `-Werror` flag.

Comment: Do you have a strong reason to use Qt 4.4.3, in 2019? I would try the latest Qt 4 release (4.8.7), for somewhat better support of modern compilers.